# CSS Class will not gain height

Tags: html, css

I have tried multiple options and narrowed it down to a specific class but I cannot seem to figure it out.

Im trying to get "#content-wrapper" to increase height but it seems to be stuck at the browsers height.

This has been pissing me off for the past 3 hours.

```
#content-wrapper { 
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1000px;
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  margin: auto;
  position: relative;
}
```

JSFiddle Link: http://jsfiddle.net/8hn7uLqr/

If anyone can help me please I will be very grateful, I hope everyone is having a good Christmas Eve!

Comment: What height do you want it at? Anything more than the window?

Comment: I basically want it to grow with the content as it should, if you look in my source code its showing that the inner content (white) is 9000px tall but for some reason #content-wrapper will not grow with it.

Comment: Because you've set the `height` to `100%`, it's doing what you told it to do.

Comment: @DavidThomas is right. You can't have the `height` attribute set to 100% because it'll overrule your inline styles in the HTML. Remove the inline and set the height you want in your CSS.

Comment: Its not doing what I told it to do.. its not increasing height and making the element look like this: http://i.gyazo.com/a70eb996e9ea4b7a96bc40d4d208e38a.png. I really dont think a 100% height item should stop midway through the page.

Comment: Not sure what you are trying to achieve with absolutely positioned divs but if you give `overflow: auto` to `#container-wrapper` it takes up the height you wanted

Answer (score 0):

Delete `height:100%` in the css for the `#wrapper` and `#content-wrapper`. It this case it means the height of your browser without scrolling. Give the height a number of pixels or let the height depend on the content within with `height:auto`.

Comment: Maybe it's because of the inline css in `.row` when I put 9000 in stead of 90 it works

Comment: Where exactly are you putting that?

Answer (score 0):

So if I understand you correctly, you're not sure why your content shows a height of `703px` when it's actually in the `9000`'s. There are 2 issues here.

1. is the use of `height: 100%`. Many people think that means 100% of the content but it's actually 100% of the current screen size unless you set `html` to be `height: 100%` as well. You can use `min-height: 100%` which will allow it to extend past the screen height.
2. The biggest issue you are having is because of the constant use of `position: absolute`. I'm not sure if you are aware but using `absolute` positioning removes the element from the flow of the document. Meaning it no longer adheres to it's parents constrains.

After I removed the multiple `position: absolute` and the `height: 100%` you can see form the following screenshot the height is adjusted to the content:

[image]

So really you need alot of CSS overhaul to set this up without `absolute: position`